# Nginx redirect HTTPS to HTTP with URL rewrite

Tags: http, nginx, https, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup an nginx reverse proxy that will receive HTTPS connections and redirect these via HTTP to our backend server.

I've got the basics correct and the reverse proxy works fine but I also need to rewrite links on the backend webpage so that the frontend hostname and port are displayed in the browser.

My config is as follows -

```
server {
       listen                  1493 ssl;
       server_name             ngx.example.com;
       ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/public.cert;
       ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/private.rsa;

location / {
       proxy_pass              http://ws1.example.com:1483;
       proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

I can browse to the page and the frontend hostname:port is displayed but clicking on any links (which also show the frontend hostname:port) returns "400 Bad Request.  The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port".  My backend is HTTP only and the error is originating from nginx.

How do I make this work? It was much easier in IIS...

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact nginx error?

Comment: can you alter the site to send back only relative links?  Then you don't need to scrape URLs out of the HTML content and modify it.

Comment: The exact error is "400 Bad Request. The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port".  I'm guessing it doesn't like the fact that I'm trying to rewrite the port in the response to match the frontend server's SSL port of 1493. I can't alter the site as it's the landing page of a bespoke service that provides references for talking to the service.

Comment: remove the `$server_port` within the `proxy_set_header` section

Comment: Removing $server_port didn't work, I end up with a "page cannot be displayed" as port is no longer being carried over.